# Is there a way by which I don't have to give the absolute pathname for any file I use while coding?

Tags: python-3.7

Whenever I am dealing with a file be it reading it or modifying it, everytime I have to use the absolute pathname for it while coding.

For eg:

```
fname = open(C:\Users\aaa\Downloads\Dummyfile.txt, r)
```

Is there a way by which I could just use the filename to use it instead of using the absolute pathname everytime I use it in my code?

For eg:

```
fname = open(Dummyfile.txt, r)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable and set it to the path:

```
from os.path import join

mypath = "C:/Users/aaa/Downloads/"
with open(join(mypath,"Dummyfile.txt"), "r") as f:
    a = f.read()
```

Or if you always use Dummyfile.txt:

```
mypath = "C:/Users/aaa/Downloads/Dummyfile.txt"
with open(mypath, "r") as f:
    a = f.read()
```